# What theme attributes do I need to override to change the blue highlight color of my dialogs?

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a theme called "greenhighlight" — this theme was generated using the [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), and inherits from the default ActionBarSherlock theme. The theme does nothing except change the highlight at the bottom of the ActionBar from blue to green.

To theme all my activities, I just do:

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.greenhighlight"...
```

This works pretty well for activities (note the green highlight on the bottom of the ActionBar):

[image: themed Android activity]

However, I'm having difficulty theming my dialogs to match my activities:

[image: default theme Android list dialog]

[image: default theme Android progress dialog]

My "greenhighlight_Dialog" theme is defined as:

```
<style name="greenhighlight_Dialog" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Dialog">
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">
        @style/greenhighlight_ProgressBar
    </item>
</style>
```

I'm inheriting from the default Sherlock dialog theme, and overriding the progress bar using the progress bar style as defined by my generated "greenhighlight" theme — you can see that the progress bar is the correct shade of green in the screenshot above.

To use the theme, I'm running the following code:

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = 
    new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.greenhighlight_Dialog);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
...
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.greenhighlight_Dialog);
...
```

My problem is that I have no idea what attributes I need to override. I've been looking through [styles.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) and [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) as recommended by the [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) doco (which notes that "the R.style reference, however, is not well documented and does not thoroughly describe the styles") — but there are a lot of styles defined on Theme.Dialog and I'm unsure as to which ones I need to override to get the change I want.

What attributes to I need to override for my dialogs to have green title text, a green highlight bar underneath the title and green check marks for checked list items?

Comment: Nice question. But please read this line at [ActionBarSherlock - Theming](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html) : *No additional dialog themes will be included. If you require some of the more advanced features of dialogs they must be implemented yourself.*

Comment: @PareshMayani: yes, I've read that line - that's why I'm implementing my own dialog theme.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I went digging around the source and came across the `alert_dialog_holo.xml` layout file. This is the divider view:

```
<View android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
```

In the `AlertController` class, it's visibility is set to `VISIBLE` if there is a title present. Since the color is hardcoded, there's not going to be a way to overwrite this with a style attribute.

This is the title view:

```
<com.android.internal.widget.DialogTitle android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
    style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

So it uses the `windowTitleStyle`. It took a lot of chasing, but I eventually found the style that uses:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
</style>
```

Following the parent styles back, I was able to change the text color only via styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/DialogWindowTitleAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogWindowTitleAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
</style>
```

Now for the divider, you can't change it via styles, but since you know the id, you can extend the `AlertDialog` class and intercept it when it creates its layout (onCreate) and change it's color. Though this is handled in the private `AlertController` class, so I'm unsure how much luck you'll have. I'll look into this more and come back if I come up with anything.

Comment: Hi jason thank you for such a great work.. It's working fine for all other stuff like changing header text color and etc. but when i tried to change header divider height or color of divider it's reflected into view. can you plz explain how to do that..                                need help...                                                                 thank you...

Comment: @nilkash, What I ended up doing to get around this was to not set the title and use a custom message layout. In my custom message layout I created my own divider that matches my theme.

Comment: @pegisys thank you reply. But I don't know override that divider color to match up with my app them.. I did lot of stuff but not able to do that. mainly for context window and dialog. I am able to change text and hear text or setting custom header for context but still not able to change color of header divider... Need your Help Thank you ...

Comment: @nilkash I only did this for the Alert Dialog, but this is what I did. First Create a layout that will be used as a custom message of the dialog [example](http://pastebin.com/hPU2BH2W). Then extend the AlertDialogBuilder class so that when the title or icon is set it updates the custom layout and not the icon and title properties [example](http://pastebin.com/zpVbR7Dw). Then you can use it in code like this [example](http://pastebin.com/YnHE085i)

Comment: What I did was use @Jason Robinson 's advice with the info above.  The only difference is for the divider I just put the style for the dialog to show no title, which then it shows no divider.  In my custom layout I then copied elements from the internal src layout and used them as my own.

Comment: Using the ID to change the colour of the divider won't work, as the ID is private in the framework. Any use of `android.R.id.titleDivider` will fail to compile.

Comment: @DanHulme You can use reflection to get that id value.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to remove the divider: just add the following line in your custom alert dialog style (please refer to AlertDialogStyle in Jason Robinson's answer):

```
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>"
```

Then the divider will gone.

If you still want to add a custom divider, you can add it in your custom content layout.